# Как встроить изображение в сообщение с текстом для telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

!Ю

Пытаюсь найти информацию как изображение разместили без ссылки и сделали как бы "Встроенным" в сообщение и пока что не могу.

Вот как здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У изображения нет раздражающей голубой полосы и не видно ссылки. Как сие провернули?)

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: используйте параметр `caption` при отправке изображения.

Answer (score 0):

Я не нашел в документации параметр который отвечает за текст но фото можно отправить

```
from telebot.types import InputMediaPhoto
with open('files/1.jpg', 'rb') as f1, open('files/2.jpg', 'rb') as f2:
        bot.send_media_group(call.message.chat.id, [InputMediaPhoto(f1), InputMediaPhoto(f2)])
```